# Hide Hyperlink if data is null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to hide the text "Apply Online!" below if the applicationURL is null.

```
<div class='sfitemShortTxtWrp'>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnApplyURL" Value='<%# Bind("ApplicationURL") %>' />        
            <a id="cmdApply" href="http://<%# Eval("ApplicationURL")%>" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold">Apply Online!</a>                
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this inside a repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide the hyperlink.

```
<a id="cmdApply" href="http://<%# Eval("ApplicationURL")%>" 
   target="_blank" 
    style="font-weight: bold; <%# string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Eval("ApplicationURL").ToString()) ? " display: none": "" %>">
Apply Online!</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to use a `HyperLink` control:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="cmdApply" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="..." Text="Apply Now" />
```

And in the code behind:

```
cmdApply.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmdApply.NavigateUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery version:

```
var text = $("#cmdApply").attr("href");

if (text == "") {
    $("#cmdApply").hide();
}
```